# Query com retorno #num! para colunas string no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, query

Fiz uma query no excel que ao rodá-la no VBA foi gerado um resultado. Dentre as colunas geradas, uma que era texto apareceu com #num! em todos os valores que não eram vazios antes.

Creio que o excel entendeu que aquela coluna era numérica mesmo não sendo, devido a ter nas primeiras colunas valores vazios (null).

Essa macro/query, serve para diversas rotinas e não queria deixar travado no código um if somente para essa coluna, ou para esse template. Existe alguma forma de não permitir isso?

Ao rodar a query no access tive sucesso. Porém mais cedo, a mesma query retornava o mesmo erro do excel. Não consigo entender.

código:

```
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & "[Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;typeguessrows=0;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[" & WS14.Name & "$] as Cadastro WHERE " & strexcelcolumnsNotNullKey
        Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
        strConnectString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDiretorioPadrao & ";"
        Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        rs2.Open strSQL, strConnectString
        With Sheets("sheet1")
            .Cells.ClearContents
            .Range("A" & 2).CopyFromRecordset rs2
        End With
            'Preencher o cabeçalho
            x = 0
            fim = 0
            For Each fld In rs2.Fields
                .Cells(1, 1 + x).Value = fld.Name
                fim = Application.Max(fim, .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1 + x).End(xlUp).Row)
                x = x + 1 'tick iterator
            Next
        End With
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

strsql final:
SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;typeguessrows=0;DATABASE=M:\Planilhas em Desenvolvimento\Layout - Base - Desenv_V2_69.25.xlsm].[Entuba$] as Cadastro WHERE CADASTRO.[Data Posição] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[ID Estratégia] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Cashflow ID] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Prazo Médio] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Dias em Atraso] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Tipo de preço] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Financeiro BRL] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Financeiro +1 BRL] is not null AND 
CADASTRO.[Financeiro +2 BRL] is not null AND

Dados:
(são muitas colunas.. vou colocar um exemplo)

Data Posição    ID Estratégia   Estratégia  Contraparte Quantidade Total    Quantidade Livre    Quantidade Caucionada Garantia  Tipo de preço   Prazo Médio Dias em Atraso  Financeiro BRL  Financeiro +1 BRL   Financeiro +2 BRL
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0       0,028   0   61.826,15   0,00    0,00
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0       0,00    0   0,00    0,00    0,00
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0       0,00    0   0,00    0,00    0,00
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0       0,00    0   0,00    0,00    0,00
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0           0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço A     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço B 0,00    0   0,00    0,00    0,00
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço C     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço D     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço E     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço A     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço B 0,00    0   0,00    0,00    0,00
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço C     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço D     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço E     0
31/01/2017  54  Ir a lua    Cliente Z   5000    1432    0   Preço A     0

Comment: Seria bom você acrescentar um trecho do código e valores hipotéticos da tabela para que o povo aqui possa analisar seu problema.

Comment: @PedroMVM, coloquei os dados ai. De qualquer forma, resolvi filtrando a coluna antes e apagando o que estava vazio. Porém é uma bela de uma marreta.